# the flash mem and camera don't work on windows xp installed by virtual box

Tags: drivers

I installed win xp by the virtual box and the camera does not work either the cd rom or flash mem.
how can i make them respond on the virtual windows?
Thanks

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, but not very good at getting it working...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to AskUbuntu, they're very good at getting Windows to work, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VM must be configured this way that it can access your physical computer's devices. Have you enabled the CD drive and USB in your VM settings?

Comment: i didn't so far, i followed the steps of win installation and finished it and it works but there are no respond of the flash mem, the camera and cd rom is virtual only.